# Show that there cannot be an entire function F such that F(x)=1−exp(2πi/x)

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry, I saw a previous post about the question here [Show that there cannot be an entire function $F$ that satisfy the following condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241795/show-that-there-cannot-be-an-entire-function-f-that-satisfy-the-following-cond), but I can not understand the answer presented, and I am taking a less theoretical version of complex analysis, with the name complex variables.

How is it related to argument principle or Rouché's theorem? I really have no idea on how to start this question. And I am completely lost after reading the solution in the old post. Can someone give some concrete hints on how to start, rather than a theoretical sketch. Thx!

Comment: What about the answer there don't you understand?

Comment: What part of the answer doesn't make sense?

Comment: The question is in a section about argument principle and Rouché's theorem, so i was wondering how to solve the problem with these two if possible. And I'm not clear about the 'holographic' part in the previous answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I really have trouble understanding the previous answer.

Comment: Holomorphic = "preserves size and orientation of angles". Analytic = "has a convergent Taylor series with $R>0$ at every point". And for complex functions of a complex variable, holomorphic = analytic = once differentiable = infinitely differentiable = why this stuff is pretty cool.

Comment: Nix the size part. $z^2$ is an obvious counterexample to that. But orientation of angles is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can actually be done with Roche/argument principle. The following is an attempt that looks like it does, but has a critical flaw I see no way around.

Let $f$ be our function, and suppose it is entire. Let $g$ be identically 1. For a fixed $0<\epsilon<1$, let $\Omega=[1+\epsilon,2]^c$. This is a connected open set with boundary $K=[1+\epsilon,2]$.  Now on $K$ we have $$1= |f(z)-g(z)| < |f(z)|+|g(z)|.$$ So by Rouche $f$ and $g$ have the same number of roots in $\Omega$. But $g$ has none and $f(1)=0$, a contradiction.

The problem? $\Omega$ isn't bounded and $K$ isn't a closed countour. Which are required in every version of this theorem I can recall. So the original question's answer is simpler and enjoys being correct.

Comment: On the definition of the set $\Omega$, there is a little $c$  superscript. What does that mean?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan Set-theoretic complement (in $\mathbb{C}$).